# How to cancel wrapping of text in ExtJs Combobox List?

Tags: extjs4.2

This my code:

```
function sim(proxy, data, delay) {
    if (typeof data !== 'string') {
        data = Ext.JSON.encode(data);
    }

    proxy.url = '/echo/json/';
    proxy.actionMethods.read = "POST";
    proxy.extraParams.json = data;
    proxy.extraParams.delay = typeof delay == 'undefined' ? 0 : delay;
}

Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    fields:['id','name'],
    proxy:{
        url:'whatever',
        type:'ajax',
        reader:{
            type:'json'
        }
    }
});

var myStore = new MyStore();

sim(myStore.proxy, [{id:2,name:'neil'},{id:3,name:'expert wanna-be expert wanna expert'}], 0);

Ext.define('MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

   initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    editable:false,
                    store: myStore, 
                    valueField: 'id',
                    displayField:'name',
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

var myForm = new MyForm({renderTo:Ext.getBody()});
```

I don't want to increase the width of the column. I want to increase width of the combobox list respective of the text size in store inorder to cancel the wrapping of text.
Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem you can try [matchFieldWidth: false](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker-cfg-matchFieldWidth) config:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    editable:false,
    store: myStore, 
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField:'name',
    matchFieldWidth: false
}
```

For additional configurations of dropdown use [listConfig option.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig)

Comment: Thanks Alexander Makarov.